# Make: Generic variable for linkages?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In make, I can accumulate include paths in `CPATH` and code paths for auto-compilation in `VPATH`.  But, I still have to manually handle my linkages, and I don't see a way to disseminate a manual variable (say: `LINKAGES`) to the auto-compilation rules.

Is there a variable where I can compose these linkages so that my object files that are auto-compiled get linked to my installed libraries?

Comment: GNU make does have `VPATH`, but it does not have `CPATH`. If it's working for you this means that you are using a `Makefile` that already has some logic and some rules. It would not be possible to guess how your binaries are being linked without seeing your `Makefile`.

Comment: What do you mean by "handle my linkages"?  Maybe you could give an example of what you want to do.

Comment: @raspy that is odd, I have set CPATH, and it works.

Comment: @donlan that was exactly my point. `CPATH` is not a standard mechanism, so if it works, it must be somehow implemented in your `Makefile` system. We will not be able to guess what other variables does your system use unless you post your `Makefile` here.

Comment: @raspy ok, I'll post everything tonight, on the clock at the moment.